# Closest greater lexicographical permutation

Tags: c++, algorithm

I wrote this algorithm to find the closest greater lexicographical permutation.
Given a word *w*, it rearranges the letters to construct another word in such a way that this new word is lexicographically greater than *w*. From all the possibilities the one that produces the smallest lexicographical word is chosen.

Any ideas to improve the algorithm, it's readability, or the style in general?

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

string closest_greater_lexicographical_permutation(string w) {
    for (auto rit = next(w.rbegin()); rit!=w.rend(); ++rit) {
        auto it = prev(rit.base());
        auto lowest_max = it;
        for (auto it_max = next(it); it_max!=w.end(); ++it_max) {
           if (string(1,*it_max) > string(1,*it)){
               if (lowest_max == it){
                   lowest_max = it_max;
               } 
               else if (string(1,*it_max) < string(1,*lowest_max)){
                   lowest_max = it_max; 
               }
           }
        }
        if (lowest_max != it){
            iter_swap(lowest_max, it);
            sort(next(it),w.end(),
                 [](auto lhs, auto rhs){
                     return string(1,lhs) < string(1,rhs);
                 });
            return w;
        }
    }
    return w;
}
```

Comment: Are you intentionally eschewing `std::next_permutation()`?  If so, consider marking this with [tag:reinventing-the-wheel].

Comment: Oh, and what's it supposed to do if there is no valid result?

Comment: If there is no valid result it just returns the same string @TobySpeight

Comment: @TobySpeight Oh, i didn't know that existed, thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: as an auto-correct you might check http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Headers and namespaces

We don't use `<vector>`, but do need `<string>`.

Bringing all names in from a namespace is problematic; `namespace std` particularly so.  It [can silently change the meaning of your program](//stackoverflow.com/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

## Bug

This loop fails when `w` is the empty string:

```
for (auto rit = next(w.rbegin()); rit!=w.rend(); ++rit) {
```

This can be fixed with an early return:

```
if (w.empty())
    return w;
```

## Algorithm

There's a standard algorithm called [`std::next_permutation()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) that does most of what we need.  The one difference is that if its input is already the last permutation, it will wrap around to the first one and indicate (by its return value) that it has done so. We can use that to return the original input string in that case.

## Tests

You've included no tests.  I think we need to test the trivial case (empty string) and at least one case where we must return a new string and one where we already have the last possible permutation.

---

## Improved code

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

std::string closest_greater_lexicographical_permutation(const std::string& input) {
    auto word = input;
    return std::next_permutation(word.begin(), word.end())
        ? word   // we changed it
        : input; // no change - already the last permutation
}

// Test program

#include <iostream>
static bool test(const std::string& input, const std::string& expected)
{
    auto const actual = closest_greater_lexicographical_permutation(input);
    if (actual == expected)
        return 0;

    std::cerr << "FAIL (\"" << input << "\"): "
        "got \"" << actual << "\" "
        "instead of \"" << expected << "\"" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    return 0
        + test("", "")
        + test("aabb", "abab")
        + test("cba", "cba")
        ;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I like that way of running the tests, I hadn't seen it before. Thank you!

Comment: It's quick and dirty compared to a full-blown unit-test framework - just enough to do the job and no more.  But I'm glad you like it!

Comment: Completely off topic but, which unit-test framework do you recommend? In my job they do something that I don't know if it makes any sense, they program the software in c++ and the the unit test in java with Junit test. Is there good frameworks for c++ in c++?

Comment: I don't have a recommendation, as I don't have wide enough experience.  I've used QTest for my Qt code, and GTest for other C++, but only enough to be able to say that they both work.